# Django 1.8- Stack trace referencing file that doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

When I run a custom command in Django 1.8.3, I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
(env)MacBook-Air:backend user$ python manage.py questions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/WeVote/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/WeVote/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/WeVote/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/user/WeVote/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/user/WeVote/wevote/questions/management/commands/questions.py", line 14, in handle
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/WeVote/backend/questions/question_files'
```

The error is valid, that filepath doesn't exist. I go to look at line 14 in `questions.py`, except that file doesn't exist. Boo.

As you can see, the file structure is different in referencing `questions.py` file. As some point, I'm sure that was the file structure. I also wrote this in Djano 1.7 and upgraded to 1.8. However, all the other custom commands (written both before and after the upgrade) are working just fine.

Just as a sanity check, I tried a

```
cd /Users/user/WeVote/wevote/questions/management/commands/
```

Nope. This is an issue because when I now edit my properly-located `questions.py` in the `management/commands` directory, the changes aren't reflected. It's like it's reading a cached version and location of this file.

Also tried deleting and rebuilding both virtualenv and database. No love on either. I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: A cached file is not probable but in any case do remove `.pyc` files. I'd assume you have some old version of the file somewhere accessible and that when it looks it up it finds that one before the newer one. Can you share questions.py? If you see this change just after upgrading - can you start a new project and compare the `manage.py` files? maybe the issue is there?

Comment: As above, I have a command to purge .pyc files are they often cause trouble when switching branches etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference for anyone coming afterwards: The comments from yuvi and Paul Collingwood above succeeded in solving my issue.  I ran

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

and the next time I ran `questions.py` everything worked well.  Thanks both for your comments.